# Magento ER diagram of 1.9.x

Tags: magento-1.9, database, architecture

I am looking for ER diagram of magento 1.9.x so that i can understand magento database flow and table-relationships. if anyone can provide me **COMPLETE ER** diagram that will really help me. Like i saw a good er diagram of prestashop but could not find such diagram of magento.

**Update**: For ER Diagram of Magento 2.1.3 check https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152061/29175 . Thanks to efforts of @Anna Völkl

Comment: So asked around on twitter a bit and @R.S come up with https://inchoo.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/09/MAGENTO_v1.3.2.4-Database_Diagram.pdf It's a bit old but should get you a long way. Will keep looking tho cause it would be kinda handy to have

Comment: I already gone through this but its very old diagram and not COMPLETE ER diagram. I am looking on latest so that i go to deeper for understanding its relationship flow.

Comment: I am still waiting for good answer.

Comment: Regarding the inchoo diagram, see http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73433/magento-database-diagram

Comment: I had checked this in past but i its not complete.

Comment: MageReverse.com was a great database information resource, but they died after 1.7.0.2 so that's the newest I can find.

Comment: This is really helpful.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I was also curious to find an updated database diagram. Actually I could not find one so I created one myself.

Magento CE 1.9.2.2 consists of 333 tables.

This is the database diagram of a fresh CE 1.9.2.2 installation:

As I cannot upload more than 2MB here, here's the [link to the full size diagram](http://anna.voelkl.at/uploads/magento/ce1922.png)

[image: Magento CE 1.9.2.2]

Comment: I am in need of magento seminar report , can u please comment the link here Madam

Comment: Not sure what you mean with "magento seminar report" but this is not related to the database diagram. You should start a new question if you need specific help.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl .. your efforts and the diagram is really useful. Big thx for this and if you get details about M2 diagram then please post the link here too though that not need of now but would beneficial in future. Thx again for above diagram.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl  ..how can i create same for magento2. if you can provide that would really beneficial for community. Looking for your response. Thank you

Comment: @Jai Anna also did a Magento 2 version, here: http://anna.voelkl.at/magento-ce-2-1-3-database-diagram/

Comment: @AnnaVölkl This is wonderful work, thank you so much for the time you must have spent on these to make the otherwise-terrifying structure of Magento's database appear so clear and intelligible.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Yes, it was a lot of work. Good to see it's useful :)

Comment: Can I give you like 143289047328947342 Up votes? You've done something good for humanity.