# Magento 2: Diagram of database tables, such as Orders, Products, etc. and their relationships

Tags: magento2, database, table, object

I'm looking for a diagram or schema of all Magento 2 database tables, such as Orders, Products, etc. and their relationships with each other.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**EDIT: Just like Magento 1 Anna Völkl created a new version for Magento 2. [Check her answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152061/5827).**

What you are looking for is an [ERD (Entity Relationship Diagram)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93relationship_model). I have searched for a Magento 2 ERD but could not find and. I think someone from the community will publish one at some point.

Here is [a blog post](http://www.venustheme.com/magento-2-database-structure/) which describes the database changes between 1.x and 2.x briefly.

[image: DB changes from M1 to M2]

So if you read that you should be able to use a 1.x ERD. Which you can find here: http://anna.voelkl.at/magento-ce-1-9-2-2-database-diagram/

[image: Magento 1.9.2.2 ERD]

Comment: Thanks Akif.  I'm new to Magento with 2.0 so I'd rather not start with older versions, but this is the best thing I've seen so far. Teşekkürler!

Answer (score 67):

More than a year ago I created the [database diagram for the Magento Community Edition 1.9.2.2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83338/magento-er-diagram-of-1-9-x/90278#90278), so it was time to create a new version :-)

Here's the database diagram of the latest **Magento Community Edition 2.1.3**:

[image: Magento Community Edition 2.1.3 database diagram]

Magento CE 2.1.3 consists of 315 tables (that's 18 tables less compared to Magento CE 1.9.2.2).

You can find more details about what has changed in this blogpost: [Magento CE 2.1.3 database diagram](http://anna.voelkl.at/magento-ce-2-1-3-database-diagram/)

Comment: Excellent work +1 from me @Anna :)

Comment: Thanks for your great efforts. I started working on it and its very helpful. Also added link of this to my old post.

Comment: Do you have better image quality ? I see nothing

Comment: The diagram was minified for the upload here. Click the link to the answer to the blogpost to find high-res image

Comment: Just wow. Making it not only intelligible, but also keeping the layout similar between the two diagrams to allow comparisons? Together, these two diagrams are a huge achievement.

Comment: Any one have Magento CE 1.9.3.4 - DB Diagram ? Please share.

Comment: Hi @AnnaVölkl , sorry to bother you with that 2 years later, but do you still have the diagram you made in high quality? The links provided in your answer are dead :/ Thank you for your work and have a nice day!

Comment: Hi @Hammerbot, that was my fault, i had a misconfiguration on my blog. Check out the links, they should be working again. You will also find the high quality diagram there.

Comment: Great! Thank you very much for all your work, very useful to me

Comment: Thank you for 2.1!! =) Is this still relevant for 2.3.0?

Comment: Magento 2 DB diagram direct link : https://anna.voelkl.at/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/ce2.1.3.png

Comment: GRATE JOB!!!!!!