# How do I call a stored procedure from Magento 2 code?

Tags: magento2, database

Can anybody share good resource where I can see ways to call Stored Procedure from Magento 2 Code.

Thanks

Comment: I guess you will enough info from https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101055/magento-2-diagram-of-database-tables-such-as-orders-products-etc-and-their

Answer (score 0):

The following **GetCustomers()** stored procedure illustrates the logic:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE GetCustomers()
BEGIN
 SELECT customerName, creditlimit
 FROM customers;
    END$$
```

**DB Connection:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$resource = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');
$connection = $resource->getConnection();
$sql = 'CALL GetCustomers()'; //This is the main query
$result = $connection->fetchAll($sql);
```

Hope this helpful. thanks. thumps up.

For more information:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/php-calling-mysql-stored-procedures/