# How hard could be to export data from Magento 1?

Tags: magento-1.9, export, database-export

Is there some use case example to export main data out from Magento version 1.9.x:

- users + personal account related data
- product catalog
- orders

Having them exported in a understandable standard format to possibly import them back to any SQL like DB

Not strictly necessary to have an automatic tool but at leas the SQL queries to be performed
to select the above without loosing related data to user/products/orders

Is it something feasible without getting crazy?

I've seen this post: 
[Magento ER diagram of 1.9.x](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/83338/magento-er-diagram-of-1-9-x)

Giving a full ER diagram of the data in Magento 1.
I'm wondering if there's around already some query or tools that starting from this knowledge performs an export like describe above

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by exporting specific tables query in database to export like this, 
mysql databsename -u username -p -e 'show tables like "table_name%"' | grep -v Tables_in | xargs mysqldump databse_name -u username -p > file to export.sql

In table_name, you can set "catalog_" this will export all the catalog table that starts with catalog.  This is one of the example I shared with you. You can change as per your need.