# Magento2 - Database diagram

Tags: magento2, database

In Magento2, Have it has the database diagram yet ? I just found diagram for magento 1.x, [Magento Database Diagram](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/73433/magento-database-diagram)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own diagramm, for example with the Mysql Workbench. For creating a diagramm go to Database -> Reverse Engineer -> follow the wizard.

Here an example where i only add a view tables to the EER Diagramm:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've created a database diagram of the latest Magento Community Edition 2.1.3:

[image: Magento Community Edition 2.1.3 database diagram]

You can find more details about what has changed in this blogpost: [Magento CE 2.1.3 database diagram](http://anna.voelkl.at/magento-ce-2-1-3-database-diagram/)